# Summarizing Shared Variable in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, sum, crystal-reports-2008

I have a formula that uses two shared numbers in it. I now need to sum this formula. If I use running total or sum functions, the formula does not show in the pick list.

The formula I need to sum is called "excel formula" and this is the calculation the formula is doing:

```
({@Shared Total Wt Lbs}*{@Shared Scrap})/100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "usual way" of creating a sum or running total does not work for a formula that holds a variable .

To get a sum of it you'll need to use a third variable.

Place the following formula in detail-section to add up the values:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar SumOfExcelFormula;
SumOfExcelFormula := SumOfExcelFormula + {@excel formula}
```

Use the following formula to show the sum:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar SumOfExcelFormula;
```

To reset the sum on every group change, put the following code in a formula-field and place it on the group header:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar SumOfExcelFormula := 0;
```

Comment: Is there a way then to have this sum reset on change of group like a running total does?